# kde plasma make taskbar show current desktop

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, taskbar

kde plasma 5.9.4
I want taskbar to show *only contents of current desktop.* I do not want to create or use an "activity."

Answer (score 2):

Right-click > `Task Manager Settings ...` > `General`
Scroll down to `Filters` and check `Show only tasks from the current desktop`.

(This is in plasmashell 5.5.5. I'm assuming 5.9.4 has the same option.)

Comment: I'm running KDE Neon and have this setting enabled, but it does not have the desired effect. It seems to be working for some applications but not for most.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Is there anything in common with the applications it works for - part of KDE for example?